# enumerate UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a lot of cells, and I want to enumerate them. So first cell has label '1', second '2' etc.
I tried

```
- (DataManageTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *objectDate = [timeResultArray objectAtIndex:(long)indexPath.row];

    DataManageTableViewCell *cell = [timeOfScheduleTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"dataCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];


    for (int i = 0; i <= [timeResultArray count]; i++)
    {
        cell.numberOfLesson.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", i];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

but i see that this is wrong, and i am stuck about another solution. Can you give me some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`cellForRowAtIndexPath` is called for each row. No need for the loop. Just do:

```
- (DataManageTableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSManagedObject *objectDate = [timeResultArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    DataManageTableViewCell *cell = [timeOfScheduleTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"dataCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.numberOfLesson.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

Please note that you are not making any use of `objectDate`. How should that be used?

Comment: there is a code with this object, i just didn't added it, cause question was about enumerating. Thank you